# Почему не меняется тема?

Tags: java, android, themes

Задаю тему, чтобы убрать заголовок программы.

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Прописываю в манифесте

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

а заголовок не убирается. Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не нужен заголовок, то стоит использовать другую тему

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```